# Im trying to download images from a website but the images url's are not working why?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using unfreez_wrapper;
using Shell32;


namespace DownloadImages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string f;
        string UrlsPath;
        int counter;
        UnFreezWrapper uf;
        string localFilename;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            uf = new UnFreezWrapper();
            counter = 0;
            localFilename = @"d:\localpath\";
            UrlsPath = @"d:\localpath\Urls\";

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#",localFilename + "test.html");
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true", localFilename + "test1.html");
                }

                f = File.ReadAllText(localFilename + "test1.html");
                test("image2.ashx", "ir=true");
        }

        private void test(string firstTag, string lastTag)
        {
            List<string> imagesUrls = new List<string>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;

            string startTag = firstTag;//"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx";
            string endTag = lastTag;//"cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa";

            startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag);

            while (startIndex > 0)
            {

                endIndex = f.IndexOf(endTag,startIndex);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                string t = f.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                imagesUrls.Add(t);
                position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
                startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag,position);
            }
            string item = imagesUrls[imagesUrls.Count - 1];
            imagesUrls.Remove(item);
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesUrls.Count; i++)
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(imagesUrls[i], UrlsPath + "Image" + counter.ToString("D6"));
                }
                counter++;
            }
            List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath).ToList();
            uf.MakeGIF(files, localFilename + "weather", 80, true);
        }
```

First im downloading this html as html file:

http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true

There there is animation of 9 different images/gifs.
I want to download each gif url.  So on the hard disk i will get 9 gifs.

When reading the file http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true in the content inside i see:

```
var imageUrls = ["/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162345&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162330&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162315&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162300&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162245&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162230&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162215&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162200&ir=true","/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162145&ir=true"];
```

And inside the List: imagesUrls i see this 9 urls:

For example this is in index 0 : image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162345&ir=true
I tried without the image2.ashx? 
But in both cases im getting an error on the line:

```
client.DownloadFile(imagesUrls[i], UrlsPath + "Image" + counter.ToString("D6"));
```

ArgumentException
Illegal characters in path

Before this when i used the test.html and the two other tags start and end it was working without any problem.

But now im using test1.html and this two tags: test("image2.ashx", "ir=true");
But getting the exception.

When i took one image url for example : image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309170015&ir=true
And tried to surf to it in chrome im getting no rsults it tried to search for it in google .

Its not even a url .

This is the full exception error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Illegal characters in path.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
       at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
       at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
       at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
       at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
       at System.Net.WebClient.GetUri(String path)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at DownloadImages.Form1.test(String firstTag, String lastTag) in d:\C-Sharp\DownloadImages\DownloadImages\DownloadImages\Form1.cs:line 79
       at DownloadImages.Form1..ctor() in d:\C-Sharp\DownloadImages\DownloadImages\DownloadImages\Form1.cs:line 45
       at DownloadImages.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\DownloadImages\DownloadImages\DownloadImages\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Then how can i download the images one by one from this url ? http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true

When i used the test.html and the startTag ""http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx": and endTag: ""cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa""
It worked perfect !

But now with test1.html and the two different tags its not working.

Comment: The problem is that the images urls not realy urls. So how can i find each image url in this animation ? http://www.sat24.com/en/eu?ir=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point of the exception, what *precisely* is in `imagesUrls[i]` ?

Are you saying that it is something like `image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162345&ir=true`

If so, you need to prepend the protocol and server to it, i.e. prepend `http://www.sat24.com/` to give a URI of `http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309162345&ir=true`

However, another problem is, you are searching for `image2.ashx` for a start tag and then `ir=true` as an end tag. Looking at the source of that page, there are numerous `image2.ashx` URIs which do *not* end with `ir=true`.

e.g. `http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?button=af260x160`

When you find the start tag in that URI, you're going to get an enormous mass of HTML before you find the end tag.